# Why don't my posts appear on page timeline?

Tags: facebook-pages, facebook-timeline

I have a business page.

When I post something FB tells me that it appears on "Posts To Page".

I want it to appear on the page's time line.

How do I get it done?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your updates are being posted as if you were a regular user. Open your page and click on this option to use Facebook as your page:

[image: use Facebook as page]

I've set my account to always do that automatically even if I don't change this, but I can't find this setting in the new preferences window.